# Excel - Sumproduct with subtotal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to have a filtered subtotal based also on dates in the DATES column being less than the specified date defined in the function.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(bank_trans[PAID OUT],ROW(bank_trans[PAID OUT])-MIN(ROW(bank_trans[PAID OUT])),,1)),bank_trans[DATE]<="30/10/2017")
```

However my formula always returns 0. Any ideas?

```
| Date       | Are | Cool |
|------------|:---:|-----:|
| 15/10/2017 | TR1 | $160 |
| 30/10/2017 | TR2 | $120 |
| 05/02/2018 | TR3 | $100 |
```

In my example I want to subtotal only transactions TR1, TR2 because they are before/equal to the cap date in the function.

Transaction TR3 is ignored because it belongs in the future.

Comment: Could you include some sample data and expected output? You can use a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to insert data with decent formatting.

Comment: please see table hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(bank_trans[Date]<=DATE(2017, 10, 30)), SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET(bank_trans[[#Headers],[PAID OUT]], ROW(bank_trans[PAID OUT])-ROW(bank_trans[#Headers]), 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do more calculations with the result, then you could just use a normal Autofilter (Data-tab -> Filter). Then you could do all kinds of filters on the date. It is a piece of cake to get $280 as a result then.